# Accessing arrays in Nunjucks template within <script>

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, nunjucks

I have an array on server side, which adds the number 1 every 10 minutes. e.g. [1, 1, 1, 1....]

I send this to the template as follows *(data() is the array as my example above)*:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.render('index', {
    results: data(),
  });
});
```

I have a script on the template which renders a graph. For this to work, the array needs to be accessible in the script.

When I access the array by:

```
var results = "{{ results }}";
```

The array ends up like:

```
["1, 1, 1, 1"]
```

I need the array without the double quotes. Is this possible?

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change it on the server or the client - I'd say let's just do it on the client side.

The entire array is made up of 1 spot that has all the values separated by commas.
We first grab that chunk of data with (["1, 1, 1, 1"][0]) - this will return just the first spot in the array with all of the data.

Then we clear out any spaces (.replace(/\s/g,'').

Turn it into a true array (split(",")).

Then turn each of those string numbers into true numbers (.map(function(e){return Number(e);}))

remove: .map(function(e){return Number(e);}) if you don't care if the numbers are strings or not.

```js
var results = ["1, 1, 1, 1"][0];
var result = results.replace(/\s/g,'').split(",").map(function(e){return Number(e);});
console.log(result);
```